# Quadruple integration using Gauss-Legendre quadrature

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I want to use Gauss-Legendre quadrature to evaluate a quadruple integral in Matlab. I found the following code that works for a double integral but when it comes to switching to 4 variables I don't know how.

```
a = 2; b=2;
[x,w] = lgwt(50);

y=(b*(1+x))/2;
x=(a*(1+x))/2;
[X, Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
fun = @(x,y) exp(1i*x)./(sqrt(x.^2+y.^2));
t = w * fun(X,Y) * w'
```

The function I would like to integrate :

```
fun = @(x,y,z,t) 1./sqrt(x.^2+y.^2+z.^2+t.^2)
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This solution](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/77571-how-to-perform-4d-integral-in-matlab#answer_87331) seems like the best option in your case.

The best way to integrate `fun = @(x,y,z,t)` from
`a <= x <= b`, `c <= y <= d`, `e <= z <= g`, and `h <= t <= i` is to nest `integral3()` with `integral()`. They are both built-in functions of Matlab.

```
Q = integral(@(x)integral3(@(y,z,t)f(x,y,z,t),c,d,e,g,h,i),a,b,'ArrayValued',true);
```